# Can you modify nouns with polite verbs in the relative clause?

Tags: grammar

学校に行く人は学生だ is the plain. So can I use the polite form such as 学校に行きます人は学生です。

Comment: `Can you modify nouns with polite verbs in the relative clause?` -> Technically, yes, but only in formal/limited contexts. Eg: 「本日ご紹介いたし**ます**商品はこちらでございます。」(TV shopping channel)「まもなく２番線に参り**ます** / 入り**ます**電車は、各駅停車京都行きです。」(train station announcement) 「只今ご紹介にあずかり**ました**山田太郎でございます」(formal speech)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example, to make the sentence into polite form you would not change the ending of 行く; e.g. 学校に行く人は学生です。 That rule applies to modified nouns. Here are a few more examples.

> あの眼鏡【めがね】を掛けている人は誰ですか。 (polite)
>
> あの眼鏡【めがね】を掛けている人は誰？ (informal)